# How to reload modules when switching between git branches in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, ipython

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. Pardon any mistakes.

I am working on a Python library. I wish to compare two different implementations of an algorithm that are present in two different git branches. The only difference between two implementations is addition of an extra `class`.

Also the comparison should be in a single jupyter notebook (reproducible). After switching between branches and reloading, I am unable to fetch that `class` added to the branch.

Here's what I have been doing in the notebook -

```py
! git checkout <implementation_branch_1>
# import libraries
# test the algorithm
# everything is all good

! git checkout <implementation_branch_2>
import importlib
importlib.reload(my_library)
# New class added to implementation_branch_2 is not visible
```

I suspect `importlib.reload` is not working all correct. Or maybe its because of version control. Any help on this is highly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reaload works with aliases.
Also, for me it only worked when I imported `importlib` before importing the module that I need to reload

```
import importlib
import my_library as ml

#Do stuff

importlib.reload(ml)

ml.new_foo()
```